# Cannot export a Document Set larger than 50 MB

Tags: sharepoint, export

In my code, I am exporting Document Sets to be imported to another library (DocumentSet.Expot()).  The maximum upload size is 100 MB.  We have some Document Sets that exceed 50 mb.  When they are larger than 50 mb, I receive an error "Cannot export a Document Set larger than 50 MB".  This only happens in our test environment.  In my development environment, I have no problems exporting Document Sets over 50 mb.  I have found a hotfix(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2544019) that sounds similar to the issue I am experiencing.  However, it seems more geared to sending items to the Record Center.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `Maximum Upload Size` for a web application is not enough since submitting Document Sets to the `Record Center` goes through `OfficialFile.asmx` Web Service which in turn has own settings.

`OfficialFile.asmx` Web Service has it own settings and it resides under: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\OfficialFile.asmx`

### Solution

Open `web.config` file located under `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\` and add the following section:

```
<location path="OfficialFile.asmx">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="240" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: I have tried this and still received the same error.  In my mind, I am not using the OfficialFile.asmx Web Service.  Not sure what SharePoint does in the background.  My code exports the document set and imports it to another library on the same site.